# p:dataTable onRowSelect - SelectEvent is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces

When I clik on my row in dataTable,argument selectEvent in my onRowSelect method is null, any ideas why???

form.xhtml file:

```
<h:form>
        <p:dataTable var="row"
                     value="#{backingBean.model}"
                     lazy="true"
                     rows="#{backingBean.model.getTablePageSize()}"
                     rowKey="#{row.id}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="#{loggedUserBean.getPageSizes()}"
                     paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                     paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     selection="#{backingBean.model.selectedRow}"
                     selectionMode="single"
                     emptyMessage="#{commonProperties.dataTableEmptyMessage}"
                     emptyMessagePosition="center">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="#{properties.title}"/>
            </f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
                    listener="#{controller.onRowSelect(args)}">
            </p:ajax>
```

controller method:

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        Row row = (Row) event.getObject();
        getBackingBean().getModel().setSelectedRow(row);
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("updateButtons();");
    }
```

Comment: How did you come to create it like this? I've never seen any tutorial or showcase where it is done like this.

Answer (score 2):

You provided unnecessary argument in your xhtml.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{controller.onRowSelect(args)}">
</p:ajax>
```

It should look like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{controller.onRowSelect}">
</p:ajax>
```

Comment: And the fact that the method **is** called can only mean that the argument is null. Since if it was e.g. not null and a string, the method signature would not have matched and you'd have gotten errors.